# JSON in swift Parsing Nested Objects

Tags: json, swift, class, nested

I have two classes with a json file. I would like to know how do I parse a nested object in json. The first class is the person class with a name and an array of pastname. The array of nicknames can be nil. The second class is the pastname class that holds list of nicknames as strings.

```
...code...

func Parse(jsonObject: [Any]?){

        //setting to correct varaible
        guard let json = jsonObject
            else{print("Error"); return}

        for items in json{
            guard let obj = items as? [String:Any],
            let name = obj["names"] as? String,
            //Error occurs here. How do i access the second level?
            let nicknames = obj["nicknames"] as? [PastNames]
            else{continue}
        }
}

//class one

    class Person{
        var name: String
        var pastNickNames: [PastNames]

        //initializers
        init(name: String, pastNickNames: [PastNames] = [PastNames]()){
            self.name = name
            self.pastNickNames = pastNickNames
        }
    }

//class two 
class PastNames{
    var nicknames: [String]!

    init(nicknames: [String]!){
        self.nicknames = nicknames
    }
}

...json...
[
  {
    "name": "Chris Hamilton",
    "nicknames": [      
          "Snitch",
          "SourFace",
          "DumbDumb",
          "Giganta",
          "McGag"     
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
struct Root: Codable {
   let name: String
   let nicknames: [String]?
}
```

---

```
do {
    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
    print(res)
  }
  catch {
    print(error)
 }
```

Comment: How would I save the data to an array of Person